# Can I make a sympy function that takes a string as well as a float as input?

Tags: symbols, sympy, wolfram-language

Coming from Wolfram Language I would expect to be able to define anything in a loose manner, so that floats and string can always be used interchangeably in my functions, like here, where I am putting a string  `2.0(1)` to muliply a symbol `x`

```
In[40]:= SinN[n_, x_] := Sin[n*x]

In[42]:= SinN["2.0(1)", x]

Out[42]= Sin["2.0(1)" x]
```

I am struggling with sympy to do the same, anyone has ideas?

I can do this, but not able to put it into a function

```
x=sympy.symbols("x",real=True)
n=sympy.symbols("n")#
expression=sympy.sin(n*x)+n*x
expression.subs(x,'2.0(1)')
```

PS
Related to this, I was thinking that it would be great indeed if there was a way to tell sympy something like to consider every variable in a cell as symbol, without having to declare (very annoying) all the variables that I want to be treated as symbols.

Comment: `sympy` runs within Python.  It can't just redefine existing Python classes, such as strings.

Comment: `from sympy.abc import *` makes basically what I wanted for the PS

Comment: it can be "undone" with ```def unload_symbols():
    for letter in dir(sympy.abc):
        if not letter.startswith('_'):
            del globals()[letter]```